# display unique field out of 10 records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My sql query is

```
select I.[Old Product Code], 
    I.[Trade Name], 
    I.[Short Name], 
    SIL.[BOM Item No_] ,
    CASE when SIL.[Dimension Group Code] = 'IOL' 
        then I.[Group Description] 
        else I.[Short Name] END as GD,
    CASE when SIL.[BOM Item No_] <> '' 
        then 'Kit' end
from [Sales Invoice Header] SIH, [Sales Invoice Line]  SIL, [Item] I 
where I.No_ =  SIL.No_ 
    and SIL.[Document No_] = 'PEXP1213-153' 
    and SIH.No_ = SIL.[Document No_] 
group by I.[Old Product Code], I.[Trade Name], I.[Short Name],  
    SIL.[Dimension Group Code], I.[Group Description], SIL.[BOM Item No_]
```

And my result is

[image: current output]

In this out of 21 rows i am having 17 rows as kit. I need to group this kit and to display in Old Product Code as Kit in one row instead of 17 rows.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do here, can you edit your question with data from your tables and then post the result you want from the query?  I don't see how the data is being grouped.

Comment: i just edited my question and posted the result..pls see to it

Comment: Can you could create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your table structure and some sample data? It might be easier to debug this.

Comment: here is my sql fiddle...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df9b5/2  ..in this i am having 17 rows as kit...i need to group together and to display these 17 rows as kit..if so then my result will contain 5 rows instead of 21 rows..can you guide me

Comment: have you seen my sql fiddle...have you got the thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you are trying to do you might be able to use something like this to return the data:

```
;with data as
(
  select I.[Old Product Code], 
      I.[Trade Name], 
      I.[Short Name], 
      SIL.[BOM Item No_] ,
      CASE when SIL.[Dimension Group Code] = 'IOL' 
          then I.[Group Description] 
          else I.[Short Name] END as GD,
      CASE when SIL.[BOM Item No_] <> '' 
          then 'Kit' end CombinedKit
  from SalesInvoiceHeader SIH
  inner join SalesInvoiceLine  SIL
    on SIH.No_ = SIL.[Document No_] 
  inner join Item I 
    on I.No_ =  SIL.No_ 
  where SIL.[Document No_] = 'PEXP1213-153' 
),
d2 as
(
  select [Old Product Code],
    [Trade Name],
    [Short Name],
    [BOM Item No_],
    GD,
    CombinedKit,
    row_number() 
      over(partition by CombinedKit order by [Old Product Code]) rn
  from data
) 
select 
    case when combinedkit = 'kit' 
        then 'Kit' else [Old Product Code] end  [Old Product Code],
    [Trade Name],
    [Short Name],
    [BOM Item No_],
    GD
    --, CombinedKit
from d2
where (CombinedKit = 'Kit' and rn = 1)
  or (CombinedKit is null)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df9b5/16)

Edit, if you want to order this in a specific way you can use `Order By` with a `CASE` statement:

```
;with data as
(
  select I.[Old Product Code], 
      I.[Trade Name], 
      I.[Short Name], 
      SIL.[BOM Item No_] ,
      CASE when SIL.[Dimension Group Code] = 'IOL' 
          then I.[Group Description] 
          else I.[Short Name] END as GD,
      CASE when SIL.[BOM Item No_] <> '' 
          then 'Kit' end CombinedKit
  from SalesInvoiceHeader SIH
  inner join SalesInvoiceLine  SIL
    on SIH.No_ = SIL.[Document No_] 
  inner join Item I 
    on I.No_ =  SIL.No_ 
  where SIL.[Document No_] = 'PEXP1213-153' 
),
d2 as
(
  select [Old Product Code],
    [Trade Name],
    [Short Name],
    [BOM Item No_],
    GD,
    CombinedKit,
    row_number() 
      over(partition by CombinedKit order by [Old Product Code]) rn
  from data
) 
select 
    case when combinedkit = 'kit' 
        then 'Kit' else [Old Product Code] end  [Old Product Code],
    [Trade Name],
    [Short Name],
    [BOM Item No_],
    GD
    --, CombinedKit
from d2
where (CombinedKit = 'Kit' and rn = 1)
  or (CombinedKit is null) 
order by 
  case when combinedkit = 'kit' then 0 else 1 end, [Old Product Code]
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df9b5/20)

Comment: thank you so much..this is what i need..but need one more thing in the result..i just want that Kit to be comes under Old Product Code column instead of individual column as CombinedKit

Comment: is it possible to make the kit to be come in the top of all the other items...Kit under old product code to be the top of the result

Comment: @Affan you can use `order by` to order the data -- see this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df9b5/20