# empty field should not be displayed in a separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

this is my sql query

```
select C.Name, C.[Name 2] ,
    C.Address, C.[Address 2],C.[Address 3], 
    C.City, C.[Post Code], C.[Contact], CR.Name as country, 
    SIH.[ARE Gr_Wt],SIH.[Total Boxes] , SIH.[Posting Date] , 
    SIH.[Country of Origin of Goods],
    CASE when C.[E-Mail] <> '' then  'E-mail: ' + C.[E-Mail] else '' end [E-Mail] 
from [Sales Invoice Header] SIH 
inner join [Customer] C 
    on C.No_ = SIH.[Sell-to Customer No_]
inner join [Country_Region] CR 
    On CR.Code = SIH.[Country of Final Destination] 
where SIH.No_ = 'PEXP1213-596'
```

in this query if my Address 3 field is not having value for all customers..i need to display this Address 3 column only if it has values...i dont want to display empty columns

Comment: Do you only want to display customers that have values in `Address 3`? Or do you only want to display `Address 3` if it has a value?

Comment: no i need to display all the customers...i need to display Address 3 field only if it has a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description and comment, it sounds like you only want to display the `Address 3` column when there is a value in it.

There is no way to display all customers but hide a column if there is no value, at least in one query you cannot do this.

If you `SELECT` all of your fields you are going to get the `Address 3` field unless you specifically filter it out but then if you filter you will not get all of the data.

For example, if you have the following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ([id] int, [name] varchar(4), [Address1] varchar(10), [Address2] varchar(4));

INSERT INTO yourtable ([id], [name], [Address1], [Address2])
VALUES
    (1, 'Test', '12345 blah', NULL),
    (2, 'John', '45 Test', 'test');
```

If I use the query (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17606/1)):

```
select id,
  name, 
  address1,
  address2
from yourtable
```

It will return all data in the table, including the record that does not have a value in the `Address2` field.

If I then don't want to show the records with an empty `Address2` I will lose records which is not what you want. (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17606/2)):

```
select id,
  name, 
  address1,
  address2
from yourtable
where address2 is not null 
  or address2 <> ''
```

There is no way to hide a column in a select list. You can only hide it by not selecting the value.

So you could perform two selects but these would not be in the same dataset. You could use the following:

```
select id,
  name, 
  address1,
  address2
from yourtable
where Address3 is not null 
  or Address3 <> '';
```

Then a second query to select the records with an empty `Address3`:

```
select id,
  name,
  address1
from yourtable
where Address3 is null 
  or Address3 = '';
```

The only other way I would suggest doing this is using a `CASE` statement to build one address string similar to this:

```
select C.Name, 
  C.[Name 2] ,
  case 
    when C.[Address 3] is not null or C.[Address 3] <> ''
    then C.Address +' '+ C.[Address 2] + ' '+ C.[Address 3]
    else C.Address +' '+ C.[Address 2] end Address, 
  C.City, 
  C.[Post Code], 
  C.[Contact], 
  CR.Name as country, 
  SIH.[ARE Gr_Wt],
  SIH.[Total Boxes], 
  SIH.[Posting Date], 
  SIH.[Country of Origin of Goods],
  CASE when C.[E-Mail] <> '' then  'E-mail: ' + C.[E-Mail] else '' end [E-Mail] 
from [Sales Invoice Header] SIH 
inner join [Customer] C 
  on C.No_ = SIH.[Sell-to Customer No_]
inner join [Country_Region] CR 
  on CR.Code = SIH.[Country of Final Destination] 
where SIH.No_ = 'PEXP1213-596'
```

This checks to see if there is a value in `Address 3`, if there is then you will concatenate all address columns into one string.  If there is not a value in `Address 3`, then it only concatenates `Address 1` and `Address 2`.

Comment: i am having doubt in this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932434/display-unique-field-out-of-10-records-in-sql...which you answered me later..i need to display the kit in the top...can you guide me